# firebase querying not working

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get info in firebase database, I want the users of one selected store,

```
"store":{
   "id1":{
     address:"location"
     "users":{
        "id": true
     }
   }
}
"users" : {
  "id":{
    "name": "tom",
    "lastname": "levine",
    "store": {
      "id1": true
    }
  }
}
```

I have the store id, and I want all the users that match whit that store.

```
const db = firebase.database();
db.ref('users').child('store').equalsTo('id1').once('value', (snapshot) =>{})
```

but it is not working, how can I do this? I don't have the userId, just the store that they belong

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten the `orderBy...` clause of your query:

```
db.ref('users').orderByChild('store/id1').once('value', (snapshot) =>{
  snapshot.forEach((user) => {
    console..log(user.key, user.val());
  });
})
```

But I'm not sure why you're loading them through a query, since you also have an inverted index of all users under each store already. I recommend reading a bit more about [creating data that scales](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout) in the Firebase documentation and my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: Not but I don't want to get all the users, just those that  belongs to a specific store. I want this return one or many users if it is the case.